# How to fail all tests within "describe" block if first test fail in protractor/jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I would like to fail whole describe block if first test fail within it? 
Is this possible with protractor/jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most probably just use the Jasmine built-in `done.fail` possibility.

[Read about it here](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction#section-58)

As an example in your question is missing, here the plain example from jasmines introduction page:

```
describe("A spec using done.fail", function() {
  var foo = function(x, callBack1, callBack2) {
    if (x) {
      setTimeout(callBack1, 0);
    } else {
      setTimeout(callBack2, 0);
    }
  };

  it("should not call the second callBack", function(done) {
    foo(true,
      done,
      function() {
        done.fail("Second callback has been called");
      }
    );
  });
});
```